# Custom UIMA annotators in IBM Watson Retrieve&Rank

Tags: ibm-watson, uima, retrieve-and-rank

Is it possible to use custom uima annotators in Retrieve&Rank service?
How can I upload my custom annotator (packaged as jar file) to the service?

I need to create an entity annotator to discover my custom domain entities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an obvious straightforward way to use a custom UIMA annotator in R&R.

Possible approaches you could use, if you want to try integrating the two though:

- Use a UIMA pipeline to annotate your documents before storing them in R&R, or as you query R&R for them. I've not tried this myself, but I've seen references to this sort of thing - e.g. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrUIMA so there might be some value in trying this
- Use the annotations from your UIMA pipeline to generate additional feature scores that the ranker you train can include in it's training. For example, if your annotator detects the presence or absence of a particular custom domain entity, it could turn this into a score that contributes to the feature scores for a search result. For an example of contributing custom feature scorers to R&R, see https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/answer-retrieval